# Interior of closed ball is an open ball in a metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $A\subset X$. The interior of $A$ is defined as

$$\textrm{int}(A):=\{a\in X: \exists r>0; B(a, r)\subset A\},$$
where $B(a, r):=\{x\in X: d(x, a)<r\}$.

Is it true that $$\textrm{int}(B[a, r])=B(a, r)$$ where $B[a, r]:=\{x\in X: d(x, a)\leq r\}$?

The inclusion $B(a, r)\subset \textrm{int}(B[a, r])$ is straightfoward using the fact that $B(a, r)$ is open and $B(a, r)\subset B[a, r]$.

Does the reverse inclusion hold?

I believe we must suppose $x\not\in B(a, r)$ and show that $x\not\in \textrm{int}(B[a, r])$. If $x\not\in B(a, r)$ then $d(x, a)\geq r$. If $d(x, a)>r$ then it is easy to show $x\not\in \textrm{int}(B[a, r])$. However, what about the case $d(x, a)=r$? It is pretty much evident every open ball centered at $x$ will also contain points of $X\setminus B[a, r]$ because $x$ lies on the boundary of $B[a, r]$ but how to show this fact?

Remark: I'm not allowed to use sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality need not hold.

Let $X=[-1,1]$ and endow $X$ with the discrete metric, $d(x,y) = 0$ if $x=y$, and $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$.

Then $B[0,1] = X$, $B(0,1)=\{0\}$. But the interior of $B[0,1]$ is $X\neq B(0,1)$.

(Or take $X=\mathbb{Z}$ with its usual distance, and look at $B[0,1]$ vs $B(0,1)$; essentially the same example, but countable)

Comment: As as matter of fact, $B(a, r)\subset \textrm{int}(B[a, r])$ is easy.

Comment: @PtF: yes, but you cannot prove equality because  you don’t always get equality.

Comment: Right. I'll try to fix the question in order to make it more interesting.

Comment: @PtF: more important is for you to review your original argument. You claimed you could “prove easily” the *equality* (using an argument you did not want to use), but surely you must have made a mistake.

Comment: I was lead to a mistake by quick thinking. When I tried to wrote it down I realized that I couldn't prove what I stated, only a single inclusion.

Comment: The equality holds in $\Bbb R^2$. Could you help me to understand how can I proceed if $d(x,y)=r$?